Newton approximation in Tao Analysis 1
I'm reading Tao's Analysis 1 and I'm confused about this. Help!
Definitions that are relevant:
Differentiability at a point:
Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $x_0 \in X$ be an element of $X$ which is also a limit point of $X$. Let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function. If the limit
$$ \lim_{x \to x_0; x \in X \setminus \{x_0\}} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} $$
converges to some real number $L$, then we say that $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ on $X$ with derivative $L$ and write $f'(x_0) := L$. If the limit does not exist, or if $x_0$ is not an element of $X$ or not a limit point of $X$, we leave $f'(x_0)$ undefined and say that $f$ is not differentiable at $x_0$ on $X$.
Definition of Newton approximation:
Let $X$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, let $x_0 \in X$ be a limit point of $X$, let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function, and let $L$ be a real number. Then the following statements are logically equivalent:
(a) $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$ on $X$ with derivative $L$.
(b) For every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $f(x)$ is $\epsilon |x - x_0|$-close to $f(x_0) + L(x - x_0)$ whenever $x \in X$ is $\delta$-close to $x_0$, i.e., we have
$$ |f(x) - (f(x_0) + L(x - x_0))| \leq \epsilon |x - x_0| $$
whenever $x \in X$ and $|x - x_0| \leq \delta$.

Isn't it algebraically the case that:
$$ L = \lim_{x \to x_0; x \in X \setminus \{x_0\}} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x - x_0} $$
$$
\begin{align*}
    \vert f(x) - (f(x_0) + L(x - x_0)) \vert &=  \vert f(x) - (f(x_0) + f(x) - f(x_0)) \vert\\
     &= \vert f(x) - (f(x_0) + f(x) - f(x_0)) \vert \\
     &= \vert f(x) -  f(x) \vert
\end{align*}
$$
How is $(f(x_0) + L(x - x_0))$ supposed to be slightly different from $f(x)$?


$$ |f(x) - (f(x_0) + L(x - x_0))|  = 
 |f(x) - (f(x_0) + f(x) - f(x_0))| $$

Why would this be the case? Just because we have
$$
L = \lim_{\substack{x \to x_0 \\ x \in X \\ x \ne x_0}} \frac{f(x) - f(x_0)}{x-x_0}
$$
does not in any way mean that
$$
f(x) - f(x_0) \stackrel{??}{=} L(x-x_0)
$$
but this seems to be the assumption you're making. For $x$ very close to $x_0$, you can only at best say they are approximately equal.
More broadly,
$$
\ell = \lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}
\text{ doesn't imply }
\ell \cdot h(x) = g(x)
$$
